# NSJSONSerialization give garbage at the end error 3840

Tags: php, mysql, json, swift

i get this `Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Garbage at end." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Garbage at end.}` error on swift when try to get data from the php page

this is the php code

```
require ('database.php');
function get_msg()
{
    global $connection;
    $query = "SELECT `sender`,`message` FROM `simply`.`chat_experimetn` WHERE `sender` = 'ken' || `sender` = 'jen' ";

$result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);

$messages = array();
while($message = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $messages[] = array('sender'=>$message['sender'],'message'=>$message['message']);
}


echo json_encode($messages);
return $messages;
```

}
[this is what the array look like in localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFpF3.png)

and this is the swift code

```
var values:NSArray = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    get();
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


func get(){
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://localhost/training_site/php/index.php")
    let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
    do{
    values = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSArray
    tableView.reloadData()
    }catch{
        print(error)
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return values.count;
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SpecialCell
    let maindata = values[indexPath.row]
    cell.username.text = maindata["sender"] as? String
    cell.password.text = maindata["message"] as? String
    //cell.num.text = maindata["FavoriteNumber"] as? String
    //cell.info.text = maindata["Info"] as? String
    return cell;

}
```

i couldnt find the solution to this. this is my last hope please help.

Comment: Kindly paste original response  here, not the image.

Comment: Show your whole PHP code. It should contain `<?php` somewhere?